# "Explode" table returned by SQL function into columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function `symbol_scan(integer)` that returns a table with three columns: `schema, table, count`.

I can perform a selection query on it like this:

```
> SELECT name, symbol_scan(id), FROM symbols;
       name       |        symbol_scan
------------------+--------------------------
 MY_FIRST_SYMBOL  | (public,random,1)
 MY_SECOND_SYMBOL | (public,another_table,1)
 UNIVERSAL        | (public,international,5)
```

Is it possible to use another query such that the column names from `symbol_scan(id)` are extracted, such that the table looks like this?

```
       name       | schema |     table     | count
------------------+--------+---------------+-------
 MY_FIRST_SYMBOL  | public | random        |   1
 MY_SECOND_SYMBOL | public | another_table |   1
 UNIVERSAL        | public | international |   5
```

Is there a way to do this?

Note: If I run `SELECT * FROM symbol_scan(1)` I will of course get three columns, but I don't know how to put the name in there, apart from putting it in the function itself.

Comment: What happens if you try `SELECT name, (symbol_scan(id)).* FROM symbols`?

Comment: @Lamak: Hey it works! You're my hero! You want to make that into an answer? (Sometimes, it seems to me, SQL just does it's own thing. I never thought of the extra parenthesis...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want on Postgres using this simple syntax:

```
SELECT name, (symbol_scan(id)).* 
FROM symbols
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a reason *why* extra the parenthesis are necessary?

Comment: @cassava not really, that was just on the documentation. Did you try without the extra parenthesis?, just `symbols_scan(id).*`?

Comment: yes I tried that, and it gave a syntax error. I guess it's just the syntax then; see PostgreSQL's [expression documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html)

Comment: @cassava Then I don't have an answer about the reason the parenthesis are needed; I just know they are needed from docs