# SQL using a function that returns a table with argument based on a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given table `T(id, val)`
and `function F(val) returns TABLE(a, b)`.
The function always return a single row.

I want the result of calling the function with every value in the table (T), but can't figure out how to do so.

I know that I should use

```
SELECT * FROM F(val)
```

but how can I combine this result for every entry in T?

Thank you all

Comment: Not sure what you're after exactly - `how can I combine this result for every entry in T?`... are you trying to aggregate data from the table? Are you maybe looking for `GROUP` functionality...?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a lateral join:

```
select f.*
from t cross join lateral
     f(t.val) f;
```

Comment: You don't need the `lateral` keyword if you are using an implicit cross join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I use the comma in this case because that's how I learned the syntax for `lateral`.  I suppose `join` is more accurate.  I like the `lateral` keyword in this case . . . but freely admit that I don't use it for `generate_series()`.  I'm feeling inconsistent.

Comment: you need `cross join`.  A "simple" `join` requires a join condition. Alternatively you can simply use `from t, f(t.val)`

Comment: After reading about it, this is exactly what I wanted, but sadly I'm limited to PostgreSQL 9.2 (it's old, I know), which is yet to include this feature. Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the answer thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440818/explode-table-returned-by-sql-function-into-columns?rq=1).

```
SELECT T.id, (F(T.val)).* 
FROM T
```

Apparently the extra parenthesis are important...

Thanks everybody!